# is there command to delete files created by pod try

Tags: ios, cocoapods

```
pod try
```

is very useful when trying a library.

After I'm done using the example, I want to delete the files created. 
For example after using

```
pod try RxSwift
```

I have to remove this folder manually

> /private/var/folders/nq/vc7lyxms2z589w3pr239dt700000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/RxSwift/

Is there a pod command to delete files created by pod try?

Answer (score 2):

In general, it is safe to delete antyhng `/private/var/folders` as that location is used for temporary data. You don't have to manually remove the content from that folder, as it would usually be "garbage collected" by the OS if there's any issue of free space.

If you're interested in doing this for some programmatic/automation reason, here's something that can work:

```sh
# try a Pod, store the path to the project in `.podtry_path`
pod try 'SomePod' | sed -En "s/Opening '(.*)'/\1/p" | rev | cut -d/ -f2- | rev > .podtry_path

# Delete the "tried" project and the temporary path cash
rm -rf `cat .podtry_path` && rm .podtry_path
```